# Merge column values of different types in linq query

Tags: c#, casting, linq-to-entities

Here is how I can return result of merging two string columns:

```
    context.DBSET.Select(e => e.STRING_PROPERTY + e.STRING_PROPERTY)...
```

How can I merge e.STRING_PROPERTY  + e.INTEGER_PROPERTY in one string result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert it to a string using [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127.aspx):

```
var results = context.DBSET
                     .Select(e => e.STRING_PROPERTY + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)e.INTEGER_PROPERTY));
```

Answer (score 0):

Several C# members are supported by Linq to Entities and Linq to Sql behind the scenes. Amoung these, are String.ToString() and DateTime.Now. You could write:

```
    context.DBSET.Select(e => e.STRING_PROPERTY + e.INTEGER_PROPERY.ToString())...
```

As @Reed pointed out, the SqlFunctions will also work, and will provide a more general, but less readable set of operations that can be performed in your query.

Comment: You will get this eror: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. ))